# Changing chrome extension html using chrome storage event listener

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, event-listener, google-chrome-storage

With this code I want to create an event listener for whenever chrome storage updates.

I want 2 things to happen when the event listener is triggered:

1. The code will console log the updated values. This part works.
2. I want the HTML for the extension (the document that opens in the corner when you click the icon) to update and render the data value that is in chrome storage. This is that part I need help with.

```
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(changes, namespace) {
      //part 1
      console.log('New data type is %s. New value is %s', 
      changes['type'].newValue, changes['data'].newValue)

      //part 2
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 
      changes['data'].newValue
});
```

I realize that calling "document" inside the function doesn't make sense, but I'm unsure how to move forward to get it to render in the extension's HTML.

I tried creating an event listener for when the context menu is accessed (users can update the chrome storage but clicking a button in the context menu) but I couldn't get it to work. Also the event should trigger when chrome storage is updated, not when the context menu is simply accessed.

Right now I get this error:
Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

(There is an element with id 'output', so that isn't the problem)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The background script runs in a separate hidden background page. It's not related to the browserAction or pageAction popup page, it doesn't have any of the popup page elements, its DOM is empty except for the auto-generated script tags of the background scripts.

The popup is also a separate page and just like any normal page its environment/DOM exists only when the page is shown. You can't modify it when it's not shown. You can't show it from your code in general case either.

**Solution 1**

Put that onChanged listener in popup.js script that's loaded in your popup.html (declared as `"browser_action": {"default_popup":"popup.html"}` in your manifest.json) using the standard `<script src="popup.js"></script>` tag. It will update the popup page if it's shown, and to display the current values when the popup opens read them with `chrome.storage.local.get` or `chrome.storage.sync.get` depending on which storage you're using in your extension.

**Solution 2**

Use [chrome.notifications API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications) to show a small notification at the bottom of the screen, see also the [official demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:notifications).

**Solution 3**

Use [chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setBadgeText) to display short text like a temperature right under the extension icon. Don't forget to declare at least `"browser_action": {}` in your manifest.json.